# How to sum time using bash?

Tags: bash, time, arithmetic

I want to know the total amount of time that a series of processes would take in my computer to decide if I should running there or in a stronger computer. So, i am forecasting the running time of each command. The output looks like:

```
process1    00:03:34
process2    00:00:35
process3    00:12:34
```

How can I sum the second column to obtain a total running time? I could try pipping each line through

```
awk '{sum += $2 } END { print sum }
```

but this makes no sense as the values are not natural numbers.

Answer (score 18):

```
#!/bin/sh

EPOCH='jan 1 1970'
sum=0

for i in 00:03:34 00:00:35 00:12:34
do
  sum="$(date -u -d "$EPOCH $i" +%s) + $sum"
done
echo $sum|bc
```

`date -u -d "jan 1 1970" +%s` gives 0. So `date -u -d "jan 1 1970 00:03:34" +%s` gives 214 secs.

Comment: Does seem a little hack-y, but hey, it works in an interesting (sort-of) way.

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot (or don't want) use `TIMEFORMAT` your just need to transfer time into seconds, then add it together. For example pipe output through:

```
{                                           
sum=0
while IFS="[ :]" proc_name h m s
do
    let sum+=$((60*($m+60*$h)+$s)) 
done 
echo $sum  
}
```

Or if you'd like can exchange last `echo`-command by

```
printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $[sum/3600] $[sum/60] $[sum%60]
```

Comment: The minutes should be `$[sum/60%60]` to strip the hours off.

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

Here is a new implementation that makes use of `dc`'s "output base."  Note that if the total sum is more than 60 hours, this will output *four* space-separated values instead of three.  (And if the total sum is less than one hour, only two space-separated values will be output.)

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt | tr : \ | dc -f - -e '60o0ddd[+r60*+r60d**+z1<a]dsaxp'
```

Input is assumed to be in triples of hour, minute, second, as shown in the question.

Output on the provided input is:

```
 16 43
```

---

**Original answer:**

Let's do this with `dc` your Desk Calculator.  It's the back-end to `bc`, and it's extremely flexible although often considered cryptic.

---

First, some pre-processing to give the times only, and convert the colons to spaces:

```
awk '{print $2}' | tr : ' '
```

We could also do this with Sed:

```
sed -En -e 's/^.*([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]).*$/\1 \2 \3/p'
```

I'll go with Awk and `tr` because it's simpler.  Either of the above command produces a clean output in the following format.  (I'm using my own example text because I consider it more interesting; it has hours included.  Yours will work as well.)

```
$ cat input
9 39 42
8 04 50
7 49 32
10 01 54
7 19 18
```

---

Given times in the above format, run them through the following Sed script and pipe the result into `dc` as shown:

```
sed -e '1s/^/0 /' -e 's/$/ r 60 * + r 60 60 * * + +/' -e '$s/$/ 60 60 * ~ 60 ~ f/' input | dc
```

(Broken down to reduce sideways scrolling:)

```
sed <input \
    -e '1s/^/0 /' \
    -e 's/$/ r 60 * + r 60 60 * * + +/' \
    -e '$s/$/ 60 60 * ~ 60 ~ f/' |
      dc
```

The output will be seconds, minutes, hours, in that sequence.  (Note this is a reversed sequence.)  **I'm just learning `dc` so this isn't a perfect solution,** but I think it's pretty good for a first look at `dc`.

Example input and output, pasted directly from my terminal:

```
$ cat input 
9 39 42
8 04 50
7 49 32
10 01 54
7 19 18
$ sed -e '1s/^/0 /' -e 's/$/ r 60 * + r 60 60 * * + +/' -e '$s/$/ 60 60 * ~ 60 ~ f/' input | dc 
16
55
42
$
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using the bash 'time' builtin command, before you run your program, you can `export TIMEFORMAT=%0R`.  The output will then be in whole seconds addable by awk.  More information is available in the 'Shell Variables' section of the bash man page.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution - use `split()`.
Printing total time in seconds:

```
awk '{
        split($2, tm, ":");
        tottm += tm[3] + tm[2] * 60 + tm[1] * 3600;
    }
    END {
        print tottm;
    }' ptime
```

Printing in nice time format:

```
awk '{
        split($2, tm, ":");
        secs += tm[3]; 
        mins += tm[2] + int(secs / 60); 
        hrs += tm[1] + int(mins / 60);
        secs %= 60; mins %= 60;
    }
    END {
        printf "%d:%d:%d\n", hrs, mins, secs;
    }' ptime
```

GNU awk also supports strftime, but it will use your current timezone, so results would be confusing.

Comment: You can call `gawk` with `TZ=UTC0 gawk...` to remove the timezone issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just split and calculate:

```
awk -F '[ :]' '
  {sum += $NF + 60 * ($(NF-1) + 60 * $(NF-2))}
  END {print sum}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation on themes here, but more pipes

```
echo """
process1    00:03:34
process2    00:00:35
process3    00:12:34
"""  | \
     sed 's/process.  *\([0-9]\)/\1/g' | \
     xargs -i{} date +%s --date "1970-1-1 {}" | \
     awk '{sum += $1; cnt +=1} 
         END {
               print sum / 60, " total minutes processing";
               print (sum / 3600) / cnt, "minutes per job"
         }'
916.717  total minutes processing
5.09287 minutes per job
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost any shell could do the math:

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=:; set +f
getseconds(){ echo "$(( ($1*60+$2)*60+$3 ))"; }

for   t in 00:03:34 00:00:35 00:12:34
do    sum=$((sum + $(getseconds $t) ))
done
printf '%s\n' "$sum"
```

Use `getseconds $=t` in zsh to get it to split.